# UITableView Section is too tall for the cells it contains

Tags: uitableview

I'm developing an application with a contacts list, and after the upgrade to IOS 7, there seems to have appeared some random gaps at the bottom of the sections. Some, but not all, sections seems to be too tall for the cells they should contain. It is not section footers as they are set to 0.01f and even returns a view with zero rect size.

No idea what this is. Anyone else had this problem?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by the fact that i had no rows in section c, and still had a section height set to 30.0f. Simply checking if the section had 0 rows and then setting height for section header view to 0 fixed. I also returned an empty view with CGRectZero for this header view

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{if(//section has no rows)return 0.0f;return30.0f;}
```